# Rails javascript_include_tag: 'type="text/javascript"' missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My instance of Ruby on Rails 4.0.0 (Ruby version 1.9.3) doesn't puts `type` attribute to `<script>` tag, when I use `javascript_include_tag` in the views.

What I should tweak in Rails to solve that problem?

Comment: It's *okay* to omit the attribute in HTML5 and the script type defaults to text/javascript. I don't know of a browser that behaves differently. Just use an HTML(5) validator and leave it as it is? If it is *really* a problem in some environment then the method can be monkey-patched there..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323376/do-html5-script-tag-need-type-javascript and http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element

Comment: Check out the answer to this question, it gives a pretty good explaination of javascipt changes in rails 3+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046787/javascript-include-tag-defaults-does-not-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the `type` attribute is not necessary.

However, if you absolutely need to define it, arbitrary attributes can be put on the tag by passing a hash as the last argument of `javascript_include_tag`.

That is,

`javascript_include_tag "test", :type => "text/javascript"`

will produce

`<script src="/javascripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Useful when using old Rails with JavaScript Modules!

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't. `<script>` tags no longer require a `type` attribute, they're assumed to be JavaScript.

> What I should tweak in Rails to solve that problem?

Nothing, because it's not a problem.

Comment: On Google Chrome console: "localhost/:7 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/".
    2015-01-24 08:08:31.293(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/javascripts/site.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: I think you are right... the output was really html not javascript. we don't need to add the :type to javascript.